# How to calculate RMSPE in python using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I am doing a multivariate forecasting using the [Rossmann dataset.](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales#description) I now need to use the RMSPE metric to evaluate my model. I saw the relevant formula [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales#evaluation). But I am not sure how to efficiently implement this using numpy. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of numpy's vectorisation capability for an error metric like this.  The following function can be used to compute RMSPE:

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Compute Root Mean Square Percentage Error between two arrays.
    '''
    loss = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)), axis=0))

    return loss
```

(For the error between vectors, `axis=0` makes it explicit that the error is computed row-wise, returning a vector.  It isn't required, as this is the default behaviour for `np.mean`.)

Comment: This gives you the right answer but the actual formula for percent error should be (y_true - y_pred) / y_true.
When you square it, it makes no difference, but just for clarity...

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is correct, or at least, it doesn't match the formula currently used by [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tools/eval_measures.html#rmspe).

Comment: @dmn the `statsmodels` implementation is much more sophisticated but fundamentally does the same thing. Notice that they define `error = y - y_hat` and then compute `error / y`. This is the same as `(y_true - y_pred) / y_true`. Then `statsmodels` squares the error, takes the mean (`nanmean`) and finally returns the `sqrt`. I have just noticed a typo in the function name I wrote though, it should have been `rmspe`...

Answer (score -2):

It should be normalized by ground truths.

[RMSPE equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIpwg.jpg)

```
def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(np.nanmean(np.square(((y_true - y_pred) / y_true))))*100
```