# How to express Root Mean Squared Error as a percentage?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mean-square-error

I want to compare the result of my prediction with that of another person's prediction. In the article, the author says 'The relative percentage of root mean square (RMS%) was used to evaluate the performance'. This is what I want to compare my prediction to.

Currently I'm calculating the root mean square error, however I don't understand how to express this as a percentage

This is how I calculate my root mean square error using Python

```
rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_predict)
```

Comment: This is less of a programming question and more of a statistics question; it might be better off at [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)! Do you mean you want the RMS error as a percentage of the data value for every data point?

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what they say there! I'm not entirely sure for your question, the report that I want to compare to expresses one value at 71% and the other value, which he says is more accurate, at 75%.

Answer (score 5):

Use numpy lib in order to calculate rmspe ([How to calculate RMSPE in python using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165807/how-to-calculate-rmspe-in-python-using-numpy)):

```
rmspe = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)), axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual_values, predictions))

target_range = np.max(actual_values) - np.min(actual_values)

percentage_accuracy = (1.0 - (rmse / target_range)) * 100
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).